# capistrano 2 : `tar' could not be found in the path on the local host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I am using Capistrano version 2 and trying to deploy code on server.

but when i enter `cap deploy:check` command i am getting below error.

```
   * executing "which tar"
    servers: ["53.79.454.474"]
    [53.79.454.474] executing command
    command finished in 1088ms
The following dependencies failed. Please check them and try again:
--> `tar' could not be found in the path on the local host
```

I also try to install tar on my remote ubuntu machine, but still getting the same error.

```
sudo apt-get install tar

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
tar is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I don't know why i am getting this error. please help

Thanks,

Comment: The error tells you that tar is not installed on the server you are trying to deploy to. What kind of os / distribution are you using (for development and production)? if on deb or ubuntu try `sudo apt-get install tar`. However, tar is usually installed with any *ni/ux distribution.

Comment: my local machine is window machine. my remote machine is ubuntu with version 14.04 .  i also did sudo apt-get install tar on remote machine but still facing the same issue.

Comment: is the repo you are trying to deploy on your local machine? Probably capistrano has the problem because there is no tar for windows. If yes, is there any chance to move the repo to the production server and change capistranos :repo_url => production@server/~/path/to/repo.git ?

Comment: repo is on another remote machine with windows operating system. if i move the repo(svn repo) from windows server to ubuntu server then will it work??

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure. It is quite common that your project repo lies somewhere on the production server. I have seen some 7zip hacks to make capistrano work with a repo on a windows machine, but you'll save many headaches when sticking to a linux distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error appears because the machine that holds your repo does not have tar installed (windows). You should have no problems when moving your :repo_url to your production server or any other server with a linux distribution.

** Edit

Before moving the repo, you could try to set the :copy_compression as :zip in your production.rb

if that fails (it might), and you absolutely want/need to stick to microsoft, there will be no way around installing cygwin with tar enabled on the machine your repo lies on and adding cygwin to your PATH variable.

Check this [google discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/capistrano/Dy8f3UiVKnQ) for more information.

Comment: can i installed tar on windows machine. ??

Comment: There are tar ports for windows, however I would try to avoid them. Check my edit for another possible solution.

Comment: I have installed cygwin and added its to path(C:\cygwin64\bin) to environment variable. still i am getting error as --> `zip' could not be found in the path on the local host
--> `unzip' could not be found in the path

Comment: have you done that on your remote windows machine? You will probably have to do that on both windows machines. However, as I said, I would recommend you to move your repo to your ubuntu server.

Comment: i installed  cygwin on local and remote window  and removed  set :copy_compression , :zip  option from deploy.rb file  and restarted my local machine. now it is working. Thanks man for the help.